# Azure Machine Learning Endpoint SQL Access fails, works in experiement

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I've created a classification endpoint using Azure ML, the input for which is a database query to retrieve the database row to classify.

When I run my experiment in the Machine Learning Studio, it works and connects properly to my database. When I submit the same query as a web service parameter on the import data module, I get the following error:

[image]
Ignoring the dangers of an SQL query as input, why am I getting this? Shouldn't it work the same?

Sidenote: I've used an SQL query on my training endpoint in the exact same way on the same database, and this didn't cause any problems.

UPDATE: It seems as if this is only a problem when I create a new endpoint for a service. If I use the default endpoint it does indeed work, but any new endpoints do not.

UPDATE 2: It also works when I submit my request as a batch run. If I use Request-Response, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft this is a known bug and they are working on it.  Another workaround, although NOT recommended, is to pass the password in as a web service parameter (but may be ok for test/proof of concept apps)

Here is a [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/065f2d9c-fbcf-43ec-abcb-27ca0b517149/classic-webservice-endpoint-cannot-access-database?forum=MachineLearning) to the thread on the MS forums that states this is a bug.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the headsup. I never really consider posting on the MS forums.. I posted on their github repo but to no avail.